# How to map words to numbers for input into Tensorflow Neural Network

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network, preprocessor

I am trying to build a chatbot with a seq2seq neural network implementation with Tensorflow in Python. I've never done seq2seq before, and most of my research has been rather unhelpful.

I'm not going to flat out ask for the code for a Sequence to Sequence chatbot. Instead, my question is how to best go about preparing a list of words as input to a network. I haven't got very far into the code, but I've made a script that will load training data from a file and tokenize it.

However, obviously a Tensorflow neural network can't accept strings as input. I need to convert these strings into data the network knows how to deal with; namely, numbers.

This is my code so far; hopefully the comments give you an idea of where I'm at:

```
#Import dependencies
import tensorflow as tf

#Fetch and preprocess data

#Define a tokenizer function
def tokenize(string):
    tokenized_list = []
    tmp_indx = 0
    for i in range(len(string)):
        if string[i] in "?.,!;":
            tokenized_list.append(string[tmp_indx:i])
            tokenized_list.append(string[i])
            tmp_indx = i+1
        elif string[i] == " ":
            tokenized_list.append(string[tmp_indx:i])
            tmp_indx = i+1

    #A quick and dirty way out :/
    tokenized_list = [x for x in tokenized_list if x!=""]


    return tokenized_list


raw_file_data = ""
with open("training_dialogue.txt") as file:
    raw_file_data = file.read()
raw_file_data = raw_file_data.split("\n")

#Train data as list of values like so: [query, target_response]
train_data = []

for i in range(0,len(raw_file_data)):
    if i%2!=0:
        #Perform the most basic tokenization algorithm
        query = tokenize(raw_file_data[i-1])
        target_response = tokenize(raw_file_data[i])
        train_data.append([query, target_response])

#Now that I have a list of tokens in the form of strings, I need to map these to numbers somehow


#Load encoder and decoder networks



#Define hyperparameters


#Train them on the data
```

It would be great if somebody could show me how to process these words into numbers somehow. I also need to be able to turn them from numbers back to words.

Comment: You may find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51123481/how-to-build-a-language-model-using-lstm-that-assigns-probability-of-occurence-f/51126064#51126064) useful.

Comment: Hmm...that is interesting. I didn't realize TF had that kind of capability.

Comment: I also just thought I might use sound sequences rather than words. This chatbot is supposed to be something similar to Siri or Google Assistant, where you can talk and they can respond.

Comment: Currently I was going to use Google speech recognition to convert speech to text, run it through the network, and then use text to speech. However, do you think it could work to simply feed in sound data as a sequence?

Comment: ...And get sound out as a response. Sorry, I'm not trying to spam, I just keep running out of chars.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the best way would be to create a dictionary / index of words mapping to numbers. This would help in converting the numbers back to words as well. The same problem is discussed at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489595/mapping-words-to-numbers-with-respect-to-definition) thread as well in the NLP context.

Code based on this suggestion -

```
wordList = []
wordMap = {}
def getNumber(word):
  if word in wordMap:
    return wordMap[word];

  wordIndex = len(wordList)
  wordList.append(word)
  wordMap[word] = wordIndex
  return wordIndex

def getWord(number):
  if number < len(wordList):
    return wordList[number]

  raise Exception("Unable to find Word for [{}]".format(number))

# Main
print(getNumber('Hello'))
print(getNumber("World"))
print(getWord(getNumber("World")))
```

Comment: Yes, I thought about this, but there are a LOT of words in the English language. I would have to find a source  where I might find such a dictionary

Comment: You should be able to use the above getNumber() and getWord() methods, they are building this library incrementally as you continue using the program. You can enhance it to write/load the wordMap dict to/from a file, if you want to reuse the mapping.

Comment: There is a way to do this directly in TensorFlow. I believe using this as an answer might be more desired.... See something along the lines of [embedding](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/embedding_column)

Comment: @sgarg, I do see that now. It could be useful. dennlinger, I have heard of embedding before, and I will look into it more. Tensorflow has a pretty steep learning curve from what I've seen, and I don't know where to find the most comprehensive guides. But I'll keep searching. Thanks for the answers, though!